# Fit cell width to content when using colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I´m trying to make the first th or td in my table match the width of the content and not stretch. Everything works fine until I introduce a colspan. Anybody have an idea of how to solve this?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>this should not stretch</td>
    <td>this should stretch</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        This is a lot of text ............................................................................ ..............................................
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td{
    border:1px solid #000;
}

tr td:first-child{
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wexdX/1173/)

Comment: use this may help you

    table{
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

Comment: in your fiddle you are using `last-child` and in CSS here you are showing `first-child`.What exactly you need ?

Comment: See if this helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/jimish/wexdX/1170/

Answer (score 0):

On the jsfiddle your provide us the code is working.

Be sure you have the property `table-layout` to auto

```
table {
   table-layout:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply remaining width for the last element like below.

```
 tr td:last-child
 {
    width:99%;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/amfkLb64/1/)

Comment: In this scenario, what if there are more than 2 columns in table? http://jsfiddle.net/jimish/amfkLb64/2/

Comment: This works fine in chrome. however, it does not seem to work in IE. 

https://jsfiddle.net/wexdX/1174/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little unorthodox, but to get all the cells flowing freely I would use more colspans

EXAMPLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/wexdX/1171/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tight" colspan="1">this should not stretch</td>
        <td colspan="2">this should stretch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this should stretch</td>
        <td class="tight" colspan="1">this should not stretch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        This is a lot of text ............................................................................ ..............................................
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td{
    border:1px solid #000;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.tight {
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```